# Send Email when Task is Assigned

Tags: workflow

I am using Project Server 2013 and SharePoint 2013.  I am trying to send an email to a specific user when a task is assigned.

Example: PM John Doe creates a task in project and assigns it to Jane Doe.  I want an email to go to manager Alex when John creates a task and assigns it to anyone.  Does anyone know what workflow needs to be created to start this?

WFM is configured completely.

I would like to clarify that I do not want an email to go to the user who the task is assigned to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SharePoint Designer,

1. Create a workflow
2. Set workflow to run when an item is created.
3. In stage body, type `email` and press enter.
4. Click on `these users`.
5. In dialog box, select the name of Manager in `To` field.

Hope it helps!

Comment: awesome.  so simple I cant believe I missed this.